# How to exclude any files under a directory in `tsconfig.js`?

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript `3.2.4` in a react project. I have some demo codes in `src/app/components/Demo/*.tsx` which I don't want to compile them. How can I exclude it from compiling? I have tried below settings in `tsconfig.jsin` file but none of them work. I still get a lot of compiling errors from `src/app/components/Demo` directory

```
"exclude": ["build", "node_modules", "**/Demo/*"]
"exclude": ["build", "node_modules", "src/app/components/Demo/*"]
"exclude": ["build", "node_modules", "**/Demo"]
"exclude": ["build", "node_modules", "**/Demo/**/*"]
"exclude": ["build", "node_modules", "src/app/components/Demo/**/*.tsx"]
"exclude": ["build", "node_modules", "src/app/components/Demo/*.tsx"]
```

Below is the compiling errors, you would see all errors are in `app/components/Demo/index.tsx` file.

```
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/joeyzhao/dev/mpost/endstate/material-ui-es/src/app/components/Demo/index.tsx(401,16)
      TS2322: Type '{ children: (string | Element)[]; align: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>, HTMLParagraphElement>'.
  Property 'align' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>, HTMLParagraphElement>'.

ERROR in /Users/joeyzhao/dev/mpost/endstate/material-ui-es/src/app/components/Demo/index.tsx
./app/components/Demo/index.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/joeyzhao/dev/mpost/endstate/material-ui-es/src/app/components/Demo/index.tsx(412,16)
      TS2322: Type '{ children: (string | Element)[]; align: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>, HTMLParagraphElement>'.
  Property 'align' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>, HTMLParagraphElement>'.

ERROR in /Users/joeyzhao/dev/mpost/endstate/material-ui-es/src/app/components/Demo/index.tsx
./app/components/Demo/index.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/joeyzhao/dev/mpost/endstate/material-ui-es/src/app/components/Demo/index.tsx(516,20)
      TS2339: Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof OutlinedTextFields'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude all files in a directory and its subdirectories using the 2-star glob:

```
"exclude": [
  "build",
  "node_modules",
  "src/app/components/Demo/**/*.tsx"
]
```

If you only want to exclude direct children files in a directory, just include one star:

```
"exclude": [
  "build",
  "node_modules",
  "src/app/components/Demo/*.tsx"
]
```

Comment: I have tried both solutions but none of them work. I still get a lot of compiling errors from `Demo` directory